# how to run a python code with impersonated Service Account

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

i am coming here after searching google but i am not able to find any answer which i can understand. Kindly help me with my query.

If i want to access GCP resource using an impersonated service account i know i can use it using commands like for example to list a bucket in a project:
gsutil -i service-account-id ls -p project-id

But how can i run a python code ex: test1.py to access the resources using impersonate service account ?
Is there any package or class that i need to use it ? if yes then how to use ? PFB the scenario and code:

*I have a pub/sub topic hosted in project-A, where owner is xyz@gmail.com and I have a python code hosted in project-B where owner is abc@gmail.com.
In project-A I have created a service account where I have added abc@gmail.com to impersonate the service account which has pub/sub admin role. Now how can I access pubsub topic via my python code in project-B without using the keys ?*

```
    """Publishes multiple messages to a Pub/Sub topic with an error handler."""
import os
from collections.abc import Callable
from concurrent import futures
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
# os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "C:\gcp_poc\key\my-GCP-project.JSON"

project_id = "my-project-id"
topic_id = "myTopic1"

publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_id)
publish_futures = []

def get_callback(publish_future: pubsub_v1.publisher.futures.Future, data: str) -> Callable[[pubsub_v1.publisher.futures.Future], None]:
    def callback(publish_future: pubsub_v1.publisher.futures.Future) -> None:
        try:
            # Wait 60 seconds for the publish call to succeed.
            print(f"Printing the publish future result here: {publish_future.result(timeout=60)}")
        except futures.TimeoutError:
            print(f"Publishing {data} timed out.")
    return callback

for i in range(4):
    data = str(i)
    # When you publish a message, the client returns a future.
    publish_future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data.encode("utf-8"))
    # Non-blocking. Publish failures are handled in the callback function.
    publish_future.add_done_callback(get_callback(publish_future, data))
    publish_futures.append(publish_future)

# Wait for all the publish futures to resolve before exiting.
futures.wait(publish_futures, return_when=futures.ALL_COMPLETED)

print(f"Published messages with error handler to {topic_path}.")
```

Comment: Read https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/master/reference/google.auth.impersonated_credentials.html

Comment: Do you want to do that on your local environment to simulate the "in the cloud" service account? (I mean, using ADC and not changing your code to perform impersonation programmatically)

Comment: yes. I have a pub/sub topic hosted in project-A, where owner is xyz@gmail.com and I have a python code hosted in project-B where owner is abc@gmail.com.
In project-A I have created a service account where I have added abc@gmail.com to impersonate the service account which has pub/sub admin role. Now how can I access pubsub topic via my python code in project-B without using the keys ?

Comment: Why do you want to perform impersonation of a service account rather than give your own account (via ADC) permission to publish to the Pub/Sub topic? Are there policies in place that prevent you having the required permissions on your user account?

Answer (score 2):

[Create](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating) a Service Account with the appropriate role. Then create a [Service Account key](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating) file and download it. Then put the path of the key file in the "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" environment variable. The Client Library will pick that key file and use it for further authentication/authorization. Please read [this official doc](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/application-default-credentials#GAC) to know more about how Application Default Credentials work.

Comment: hi Avinash, thanks for the response. But I already know the method that you shared, if you see my code above I have commented that line which picks the creds from the .key file.
What I am looking for is accessing resources without the key from my python code i.e. via service account impersonation.

Answer (score 0):

I think here is a possible example of how to do it https://github.com/salrashid123/gcp_pubsub_message_encryption/blob/master/2_svc/publisher.py#L93

From my understanding, you need to extract the `keyId` from `https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/{}:signBlob` and then pass it on the the client command (in your case `publisher.publish`).

P.S.: I haven't tested the script, it is 2 years old, but the approach looks right to me.